# Operating on sets to split into individual elements

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

There are four piles of coins, of size $165$, $243$, $273$ and $455$, respectively.  You have two legal operations:

- You can merge any two piles to form a new pile
- If a pile has an even number of coins you can split it into two piles of equal size.

Show a sequence of operations that leads to $1136$ piles each of size $1$ coin, or prove that there is no such sequence.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I noticed you failed to include that here.

Comment: You are correct, and correct to criticize me for it.  (Rather late!)  In fact, though (rather late!), I recalled I tried writing code but it never converged, so large were the number of candidate operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

Just read the (machine-generated) step-by-step solution below. Each array tells you the size of the pile, and the frequency, and each new line either combines two piles, or splits a pile of size $k$ into $2^n$ pieces, where $2^n||k$.

```
[165: 1, 243: 1, 273: 1, 455: 1]
[165: 1, 243: 1, 728: 1]
[91: 8, 165: 1, 243: 1]
[91: 8, 408: 1]
[51: 8, 91: 8]
[51: 7, 91: 7, 142: 1]
[51: 7, 71: 2, 91: 7]
[51: 7, 71: 1, 91: 6, 162: 1]
[51: 7, 71: 1, 81: 2, 91: 6]
[51: 7, 71: 1, 81: 1, 91: 5, 172: 1]
[43: 4, 51: 7, 71: 1, 81: 1, 91: 5]
[43: 4, 51: 7, 71: 1, 91: 4, 172: 1]
[43: 8, 51: 7, 71: 1, 91: 4]
[43: 8, 51: 7, 91: 3, 162: 1]
[43: 8, 51: 7, 81: 2, 91: 3]
[43: 8, 51: 7, 81: 1, 91: 2, 172: 1]
[43: 12, 51: 7, 81: 1, 91: 2]
[43: 12, 51: 7, 91: 1, 172: 1]
[43: 16, 51: 7, 91: 1]
[43: 16, 51: 6, 142: 1]
[43: 16, 51: 6, 71: 2]
[43: 16, 51: 5, 71: 1, 122: 1]
[43: 16, 51: 5, 61: 2, 71: 1]
[43: 16, 51: 5, 61: 1, 132: 1]
[33: 4, 43: 16, 51: 5, 61: 1]
[33: 4, 43: 16, 51: 4, 112: 1]
[7: 16, 33: 4, 43: 16, 51: 4]
[7: 16, 33: 4, 43: 15, 51: 3, 94: 1]
[7: 16, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 2, 51: 3]
[7: 16, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 1, 51: 2, 98: 1]
[7: 16, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 1, 49: 2, 51: 2]
[7: 16, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 1, 49: 1, 51: 1, 100: 1]
[7: 16, 25: 4, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 1, 49: 1, 51: 1]
[7: 16, 25: 4, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 1, 100: 1]
[7: 16, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 15, 47: 1]
[7: 16, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 14, 90: 1]
[7: 16, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 14, 45: 2]
[7: 16, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 13, 45: 1, 88: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 8, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 13, 45: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 8, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 12, 88: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 25: 8, 33: 4, 43: 12]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 25: 8, 33: 3, 43: 11, 76: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 4, 25: 8, 33: 3, 43: 11]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 4, 25: 8, 33: 2, 43: 10, 76: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 8, 25: 8, 33: 2, 43: 10]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 8, 25: 8, 33: 1, 43: 9, 76: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 12, 25: 8, 33: 1, 43: 9]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 12, 25: 8, 43: 8, 76: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 16, 25: 8, 43: 8]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 19: 16, 25: 7, 43: 7, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 4, 19: 16, 25: 7, 43: 7]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 4, 19: 16, 25: 6, 43: 6, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 8, 19: 16, 25: 6, 43: 6]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 8, 19: 16, 25: 5, 43: 5, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 12, 19: 16, 25: 5, 43: 5]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 12, 19: 16, 25: 4, 43: 4, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 16, 19: 16, 25: 4, 43: 4]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 16, 19: 16, 25: 3, 43: 3, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 20, 19: 16, 25: 3, 43: 3]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 20, 19: 16, 25: 2, 43: 2, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 24, 19: 16, 25: 2, 43: 2]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 24, 19: 16, 25: 1, 43: 1, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 28, 19: 16, 25: 1, 43: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 28, 19: 16, 68: 1]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 32, 19: 16]
[7: 16, 11: 16, 17: 31, 19: 15, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 4, 11: 16, 17: 31, 19: 15]
[7: 16, 9: 4, 11: 16, 17: 30, 19: 14, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 8, 11: 16, 17: 30, 19: 14]
[7: 16, 9: 8, 11: 16, 17: 29, 19: 13, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 12, 11: 16, 17: 29, 19: 13]
[7: 16, 9: 12, 11: 16, 17: 28, 19: 12, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 16, 11: 16, 17: 28, 19: 12]
[7: 16, 9: 16, 11: 16, 17: 27, 19: 11, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 20, 11: 16, 17: 27, 19: 11]
[7: 16, 9: 20, 11: 16, 17: 26, 19: 10, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 24, 11: 16, 17: 26, 19: 10]
[7: 16, 9: 24, 11: 16, 17: 25, 19: 9, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 28, 11: 16, 17: 25, 19: 9]
[7: 16, 9: 28, 11: 16, 17: 24, 19: 8, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 32, 11: 16, 17: 24, 19: 8]
[7: 16, 9: 32, 11: 16, 17: 23, 19: 7, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 36, 11: 16, 17: 23, 19: 7]
[7: 16, 9: 36, 11: 16, 17: 22, 19: 6, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 40, 11: 16, 17: 22, 19: 6]
[7: 16, 9: 40, 11: 16, 17: 21, 19: 5, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 44, 11: 16, 17: 21, 19: 5]
[7: 16, 9: 44, 11: 16, 17: 20, 19: 4, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 48, 11: 16, 17: 20, 19: 4]
[7: 16, 9: 48, 11: 16, 17: 19, 19: 3, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 52, 11: 16, 17: 19, 19: 3]
[7: 16, 9: 52, 11: 16, 17: 18, 19: 2, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 56, 11: 16, 17: 18, 19: 2]
[7: 16, 9: 56, 11: 16, 17: 17, 19: 1, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 60, 11: 16, 17: 17, 19: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 60, 11: 16, 17: 16, 36: 1]
[7: 16, 9: 64, 11: 16, 17: 16]
[7: 16, 9: 64, 11: 15, 17: 15, 28: 1]
[7: 20, 9: 64, 11: 15, 17: 15]
[7: 20, 9: 64, 11: 14, 17: 14, 28: 1]
[7: 24, 9: 64, 11: 14, 17: 14]
[7: 24, 9: 64, 11: 13, 17: 13, 28: 1]
[7: 28, 9: 64, 11: 13, 17: 13]
[7: 28, 9: 64, 11: 12, 17: 12, 28: 1]
[7: 32, 9: 64, 11: 12, 17: 12]
[7: 32, 9: 64, 11: 11, 17: 11, 28: 1]
[7: 36, 9: 64, 11: 11, 17: 11]
[7: 36, 9: 64, 11: 10, 17: 10, 28: 1]
[7: 40, 9: 64, 11: 10, 17: 10]
[7: 40, 9: 64, 11: 9, 17: 9, 28: 1]
[7: 44, 9: 64, 11: 9, 17: 9]
[7: 44, 9: 64, 11: 8, 17: 8, 28: 1]
[7: 48, 9: 64, 11: 8, 17: 8]
[7: 48, 9: 64, 11: 7, 17: 7, 28: 1]
[7: 52, 9: 64, 11: 7, 17: 7]
[7: 52, 9: 64, 11: 6, 17: 6, 28: 1]
[7: 56, 9: 64, 11: 6, 17: 6]
[7: 56, 9: 64, 11: 5, 17: 5, 28: 1]
[7: 60, 9: 64, 11: 5, 17: 5]
[7: 60, 9: 64, 11: 4, 17: 4, 28: 1]
[7: 64, 9: 64, 11: 4, 17: 4]
[7: 64, 9: 64, 11: 3, 17: 3, 28: 1]
[7: 68, 9: 64, 11: 3, 17: 3]
[7: 68, 9: 64, 11: 2, 17: 2, 28: 1]
[7: 72, 9: 64, 11: 2, 17: 2]
[7: 72, 9: 64, 11: 1, 17: 1, 28: 1]
[7: 76, 9: 64, 11: 1, 17: 1]
[7: 76, 9: 64, 28: 1]
[7: 80, 9: 64]
[7: 79, 9: 63, 16: 1]
[1: 16, 7: 79, 9: 63]
[1: 16, 7: 78, 9: 62, 16: 1]
[1: 32, 7: 78, 9: 62]
[1: 32, 7: 77, 9: 61, 16: 1]
[1: 48, 7: 77, 9: 61]
[1: 48, 7: 76, 9: 60, 16: 1]
[1: 64, 7: 76, 9: 60]
[1: 64, 7: 75, 9: 59, 16: 1]
[1: 80, 7: 75, 9: 59]
[1: 80, 7: 74, 9: 58, 16: 1]
[1: 96, 7: 74, 9: 58]
[1: 96, 7: 73, 9: 57, 16: 1]
[1: 112, 7: 73, 9: 57]
[1: 112, 7: 72, 9: 56, 16: 1]
[1: 128, 7: 72, 9: 56]
[1: 128, 7: 71, 9: 55, 16: 1]
[1: 144, 7: 71, 9: 55]
[1: 144, 7: 70, 9: 54, 16: 1]
[1: 160, 7: 70, 9: 54]
[1: 160, 7: 69, 9: 53, 16: 1]
[1: 176, 7: 69, 9: 53]
[1: 176, 7: 68, 9: 52, 16: 1]
[1: 192, 7: 68, 9: 52]
[1: 192, 7: 67, 9: 51, 16: 1]
[1: 208, 7: 67, 9: 51]
[1: 208, 7: 66, 9: 50, 16: 1]
[1: 224, 7: 66, 9: 50]
[1: 224, 7: 65, 9: 49, 16: 1]
[1: 240, 7: 65, 9: 49]
[1: 240, 7: 64, 9: 48, 16: 1]
[1: 256, 7: 64, 9: 48]
[1: 256, 7: 63, 9: 47, 16: 1]
[1: 272, 7: 63, 9: 47]
[1: 272, 7: 62, 9: 46, 16: 1]
[1: 288, 7: 62, 9: 46]
[1: 288, 7: 61, 9: 45, 16: 1]
[1: 304, 7: 61, 9: 45]
[1: 304, 7: 60, 9: 44, 16: 1]
[1: 320, 7: 60, 9: 44]
[1: 320, 7: 59, 9: 43, 16: 1]
[1: 336, 7: 59, 9: 43]
[1: 336, 7: 58, 9: 42, 16: 1]
[1: 352, 7: 58, 9: 42]
[1: 352, 7: 57, 9: 41, 16: 1]
[1: 368, 7: 57, 9: 41]
[1: 368, 7: 56, 9: 40, 16: 1]
[1: 384, 7: 56, 9: 40]
[1: 384, 7: 55, 9: 39, 16: 1]
[1: 400, 7: 55, 9: 39]
[1: 400, 7: 54, 9: 38, 16: 1]
[1: 416, 7: 54, 9: 38]
[1: 416, 7: 53, 9: 37, 16: 1]
[1: 432, 7: 53, 9: 37]
[1: 432, 7: 52, 9: 36, 16: 1]
[1: 448, 7: 52, 9: 36]
[1: 448, 7: 51, 9: 35, 16: 1]
[1: 464, 7: 51, 9: 35]
[1: 464, 7: 50, 9: 34, 16: 1]
[1: 480, 7: 50, 9: 34]
[1: 480, 7: 49, 9: 33, 16: 1]
[1: 496, 7: 49, 9: 33]
[1: 496, 7: 48, 9: 32, 16: 1]
[1: 512, 7: 48, 9: 32]
[1: 512, 7: 47, 9: 31, 16: 1]
[1: 528, 7: 47, 9: 31]
[1: 528, 7: 46, 9: 30, 16: 1]
[1: 544, 7: 46, 9: 30]
[1: 544, 7: 45, 9: 29, 16: 1]
[1: 560, 7: 45, 9: 29]
[1: 560, 7: 44, 9: 28, 16: 1]
[1: 576, 7: 44, 9: 28]
[1: 576, 7: 43, 9: 27, 16: 1]
[1: 592, 7: 43, 9: 27]
[1: 592, 7: 42, 9: 26, 16: 1]
[1: 608, 7: 42, 9: 26]
[1: 608, 7: 41, 9: 25, 16: 1]
[1: 624, 7: 41, 9: 25]
[1: 624, 7: 40, 9: 24, 16: 1]
[1: 640, 7: 40, 9: 24]
[1: 640, 7: 39, 9: 23, 16: 1]
[1: 656, 7: 39, 9: 23]
[1: 656, 7: 38, 9: 22, 16: 1]
[1: 672, 7: 38, 9: 22]
[1: 672, 7: 37, 9: 21, 16: 1]
[1: 688, 7: 37, 9: 21]
[1: 688, 7: 36, 9: 20, 16: 1]
[1: 704, 7: 36, 9: 20]
[1: 704, 7: 35, 9: 19, 16: 1]
[1: 720, 7: 35, 9: 19]
[1: 720, 7: 34, 9: 18, 16: 1]
[1: 736, 7: 34, 9: 18]
[1: 736, 7: 33, 9: 17, 16: 1]
[1: 752, 7: 33, 9: 17]
[1: 752, 7: 32, 9: 16, 16: 1]
[1: 768, 7: 32, 9: 16]
[1: 768, 7: 31, 9: 15, 16: 1]
[1: 784, 7: 31, 9: 15]
[1: 784, 7: 30, 9: 14, 16: 1]
[1: 800, 7: 30, 9: 14]
[1: 800, 7: 29, 9: 13, 16: 1]
[1: 816, 7: 29, 9: 13]
[1: 816, 7: 28, 9: 12, 16: 1]
[1: 832, 7: 28, 9: 12]
[1: 832, 7: 27, 9: 11, 16: 1]
[1: 848, 7: 27, 9: 11]
[1: 848, 7: 26, 9: 10, 16: 1]
[1: 864, 7: 26, 9: 10]
[1: 864, 7: 25, 9: 9, 16: 1]
[1: 880, 7: 25, 9: 9]
[1: 880, 7: 24, 9: 8, 16: 1]
[1: 896, 7: 24, 9: 8]
[1: 896, 7: 23, 9: 7, 16: 1]
[1: 912, 7: 23, 9: 7]
[1: 912, 7: 22, 9: 6, 16: 1]
[1: 928, 7: 22, 9: 6]
[1: 928, 7: 21, 9: 5, 16: 1]
[1: 944, 7: 21, 9: 5]
[1: 944, 7: 20, 9: 4, 16: 1]
[1: 960, 7: 20, 9: 4]
[1: 960, 7: 19, 9: 3, 16: 1]
[1: 976, 7: 19, 9: 3]
[1: 976, 7: 18, 9: 2, 16: 1]
[1: 992, 7: 18, 9: 2]
[1: 992, 7: 17, 9: 1, 16: 1]
[1: 1008, 7: 17, 9: 1]
[1: 1008, 7: 16, 16: 1]
[1: 1024, 7: 16]
[1: 1023, 7: 15, 8: 1]
[1: 1031, 7: 15]
[1: 1030, 7: 14, 8: 1]
[1: 1038, 7: 14]
[1: 1037, 7: 13, 8: 1]
[1: 1045, 7: 13]
[1: 1044, 7: 12, 8: 1]
[1: 1052, 7: 12]
[1: 1051, 7: 11, 8: 1]
[1: 1059, 7: 11]
[1: 1058, 7: 10, 8: 1]
[1: 1066, 7: 10]
[1: 1065, 7: 9, 8: 1]
[1: 1073, 7: 9]
[1: 1072, 7: 8, 8: 1]
[1: 1080, 7: 8]
[1: 1079, 7: 7, 8: 1]
[1: 1087, 7: 7]
[1: 1086, 7: 6, 8: 1]
[1: 1094, 7: 6]
[1: 1093, 7: 5, 8: 1]
[1: 1101, 7: 5]
[1: 1100, 7: 4, 8: 1]
[1: 1108, 7: 4]
[1: 1107, 7: 3, 8: 1]
[1: 1115, 7: 3]
[1: 1114, 7: 2, 8: 1]
[1: 1122, 7: 2]
[1: 1121, 7: 1, 8: 1]
[1: 1129, 7: 1]
[1: 1128, 8: 1]
[1: 1136]
```

Comment: Oh geez... great.  Thanks!  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: What method did you use to find the solution? That solution doesn't seem to be either brute-force nor a simple greedy algorithm

Comment: it's a greedy algorithm, except with the constraint that if the program will instantly lose it avoids the move (a loss happens when the gcd of all pieces is divisible by a nontrivial odd number)

Comment: Very interesting. Will the greedy approach always find a solution if there is one?

Comment: I haven't really thought about it. The intuition was that we had lots of moves available so a greedy approach would probably work, provided we don't throw ourselves directly off a cliff. It wouldn't be too surprising if the greedy approach was guaranteed to win though (and this would result in a complete characterisation of which initial states are winnable).